# How to link to other HTML files within a template HTML file using html-webpack-plugin

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, plugins, loader

I have used the html-webpack-plugin to generate multiple HTML files within the dist folder. They rely on their own template files, and when I update the template files then the 'dynamic' webpack version is also updated, which shows that it is working. My issue is that I want to link to the other HTML files in a nav bar.

If I link to the template files, it won't work because the source is not the same once the template files are compiled into the webpack version.

Inside webpack.common.js:

```
plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./src/templates/template-index.html"
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'subjects.html',
            template: "./src/templates/template-subjects.html"
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'prices.html',
            template: "./src/templates/template-prices.html"
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'faq.html',
            template: "./src/templates/template-faq.html"
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'resources.html',
            template: "./src/templates/template-resources.html"
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'contact.html',
            template: "./src/templates/template-contact.html"
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'reviews.html',
            template: "./src/templates/template-reviews.html"
        })
    ],
```

Inside template-index.html:

```
<div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="./template-subjects.html">Subjects</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="./template-prices.html">Price guide</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="./template-faq.html">FAQ's</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="./template-reviews.html">Testimonials</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="./template-resources.html">Study resources</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="./template-contact.html">Contact us</a>
        </div>
```

If I then run npm build and try to click on the nav links the error message says: Cannot GET /template-subjects.html

Comment: filename should have the name you have in the menu
filename: 'template-subject.html', filename: 'tempalte-price.html' e.t.c.
You do not need to call HtmlWebpackPlugin a lot, look at this example https://github.com/tomik23/webpack-multiple-entry/blob/master/webpack.config.js